# Publishing fails in SI4T Solr Search with error multiple values encountered for non multiValued field skill

Tags: web8.5, search, si4t, publishingfailed, solr

We have migrated SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5 and we configured SI4T AWS Cloud Search and SI4T Solr Search.

When I configured Indexers Individually I have not faced any issues, when I configured Both Indexers together I have received below error for Solr.

> multiple values encountered for non multiValued field skill

Error Trace:

```
2018-12-26 16:21:32,602 ERROR TridionCommitStep - Commit failed for execution id:tcm:0-2419703-66560
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Unable to commit transactions. ExecutionId:tcm:0-2419703-66560
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.commitTransaction(TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.java:78)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionCommitStep.process(TridionCommitStep.java:28)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Commit failed for transaction tcm:0-2419703-66560 because of ERROR: [doc=dcp:32-289919-288708] multiple values encountered for non multiValued field skill: [listening, vocabulary]
    at com.tridion.storage.management.TransactionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionManagerImpl.java:70)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.commitTransaction(StorageManagerFactory.java:226)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.commitTransaction(TridionTransactionalExecutableStep.java:76)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: ERROR: [doc=dcp:32-289919-288708] multiple values encountered for non multiValued field skill: [listening, vocabulary]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:424)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:180)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:102)
    at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexDispatcher.addDocuments(SolrIndexDispatcher.java:277)
    at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer.dispatchAddContentToSolr(SolrIndexer.java:445)
    at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer.commitAddContentToSolr(SolrIndexer.java:422)
    at org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer.commit(SolrIndexer.java:307)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.SearchIndexProcessor.triggerIndexing(SearchIndexProcessor.java:274)
    at com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory.commitTransaction(JPASearchDAOFactory.java:189)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.TransactionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionManagerImpl.java:65)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

AWS Cloud Search Items published without any issues.

Updated CD Storage Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
        <Namespace default="tcm"/>
        <Global>
            <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
                <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
                    <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
                </Policy>
                <Features>
                    <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
                </Features>
            </ObjectCache>
            <Storages>
                <StorageBindings>
                    <Bundle src="SearchDAOBundle.xml"/>
                </StorageBindings>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory" Id="sqlserver" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                    <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                        <Property Name="serverName" Value="SERVERNAME"/>
                        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_Live"/>
                        <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBroker"/>
                        <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
                    </DataSource>
                    <Indexer Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" DefaultCoreUrl="http://we100/solr/web8_shard1_replica1" DocExtensions="txt" Mode="http">
                        <Urls>
                            <!-- SI4T: 
                                        The Value attribute is the complete URL to a Solr Core
                                        The Id attribute denotes a unique Tridion Publication Id
                                -->
                            <Url Id="123" Value="http://we100/solr/web8_shard1_replica1"/>
                        </Urls>
                    </Indexer>
                </Storage>
<Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory" Id="defaultdb" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                    <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                        <Property Name="serverName" Value="SERVERNAME"/>
                        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_Live"/>
                        <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBroker"/>
                        <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
                    </DataSource>
                    <Indexer Class="org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer" DocExtensions="txt" access_key_id="****" authentication="explicit" documentEndpoint="****.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com" indexBatchSize="20" secret_access_key="****"/>
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false">
                    <Root Path="D:\DevLive\live"/>
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="cie_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                    <Root Path="D:\DevLive\live\C\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ocr_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                    <Root Path="D:\DevLive\live\OC\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ce_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                    <Root Path="D:\DevLive\live\EL\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
                </Storage>
            </Storages>
            <Transaction MonitorInterval="5000" Timeout="10000000"/>
        </Global>
        <ItemTypes cached="false" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
            <Publication Id="31" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
                <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="cie_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
            </Publication>
            <Publication Id="33" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
                <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="ocr_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
            </Publication>
            <Publication Id="32" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
                <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".htm" storageId="defaultdb" typeMapping="Page"/>
                <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="ce_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
            </Publication>
            <Publication Id="141" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Publication Id="142" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Publication Id="123" cached="true" defaultStorageId="sqlserver"/>
        </ItemTypes>
        <ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="encrypted:****" ConnectionTimeout="20000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="http://DOMAIN-dev.:9082/discovery.svc" TokenServiceUrl="http://DOMAIN-dev.:9082/token.svc">
            <Roles>
                <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://DOMAIN-dev.:9084/httpupload">
                    <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
                </Role>
            </Roles>
        </ConfigRepository>
    </Configuration>
```

Search DAO Bundle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StorageDAOBundles>
    <StorageDAOBundle type="persistence">
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="Page" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchPageDAO"/>
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="Binary" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchBinaryContentDAO"/>
        <StorageDAO typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO"/>
    </StorageDAOBundle>
</StorageDAOBundles>
```

New error trace with sqlserver storage node as 1st in sequence

```
2019-01-03 03:29:18,645 ERROR StepActor - Step 'ComponentDeploy' for 'tcm:0-2419739-66560': 
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Could not deploy component  [Component id=tcm:123-379958-16 title=OCR AS/A Level Classical Greek schema=tcm:123-208403-8]
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.process(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: No Data Access Object Factory for defaultdb.  Check if the default file system is properly defined and ItemTypes defaultStorageId is correct.
    at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getDAOFactoryForStorageId(StorageManagerImpl.java:306)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getOriginalDAO(StorageManagerImpl.java:175)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getDAO(StorageManagerImpl.java:151)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:175)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:121)
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.ComponentMetaHandler.deploy(ComponentMetaHandler.java:56)
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:101)
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:69)
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy.processComponent(ComponentDeploy.java:167)
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy.process(ComponentDeploy.java:101)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.process(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:91)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

New error trace with sqlserver storage node as 2nd in sequence

```
2019-01-03 03:35:11,728 ERROR StepActor - Step 'ComponentDeploy' for 'tcm:0-2419741-66560': 
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Could not deploy component  [Component id=tcm:32-289781-16 title=Activity - c1g002 - Which as a relative pronoun schema=tcm:32-288558-8]
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.process(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.tridion.broker.StorageException: No Data Access Object Factory for sqlserver.  Check if the default file system is properly defined and ItemTypes defaultStorageId is correct.
    at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getDAOFactoryForStorageId(StorageManagerImpl.java:306)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getOriginalDAO(StorageManagerImpl.java:175)
    at com.tridion.storage.management.StorageManagerImpl.getDAO(StorageManagerImpl.java:151)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:175)
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:121)
    at com.tridion.storage.deploy.ComponentMetaHandler.deploy(ComponentMetaHandler.java:56)
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:101)
    at com.tridion.deployer.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:69)
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy.processComponent(ComponentDeploy.java:167)
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy.process(ComponentDeploy.java:101)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionDeployerStepAdapter.process(TridionDeployerStepAdapter.java:91)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Based on Input received to locate exact error i followed below approach

I created 2 storage nodes without Indexer and published items related to Solr and AWS both are successful

When I add Indexers for both and when sqlserver node as 1st in sequence, i have received

> No Data Access Object Factory for defaultdb.

When I add defaultdb node as 1st in sequence, i have received

> No Data Access Object Factory for sqlserver

Error log when configured FSSearchDAOFactory

```
2019-01-05 10:48:06,887 DEBUG EntityPrinter - com.sdl.delivery.deployer.jpa.domain.PipelineEntity{executionEntity=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.jpa.domain.ExecutionEntity#tcm:0-2419749-66560, startTime=2019-01-05T10:47:58.620Z[Europe/London], stepEntities=[com.sdl.delivery.deployer.jpa.domain.StepEntity#component[executionId,pipelineId,stepId]{executionId=tcm:0-2419749-66560, stepId=ComponentDeploy, pipelineId=Tridion-Process-Deploy}, com.sdl.delivery.deployer.jpa.domain.StepEntity#component[executionId,pipelineId,stepId]{executionId=tcm:0-2419749-66560, stepId=BinaryDeploy, pipelineId=Tridion-Process-Deploy}, com.sdl.delivery.deployer.jpa.domain.StepEntity#component[executionId,pipelineId,stepId]{executionId=tcm:0-2419749-66560, stepId=SchemaDeploy, pipelineId=Tridion-Process-Deploy}, com.sdl.delivery.deployer.jpa.domain.StepEntity#component[executionId,pipelineId,stepId]{executionId=tcm:0-2419749-66560, stepId=PageDeploy, pipelineId=Tridion-Process-Deploy}], endTime=2019-01-05T10:48:01.513Z[Europe/London], statusMessage=Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'FSSearchDAOFactory' is defined, pipelinePK=component[executionId,pipelineId]{executionId=tcm:0-2419749-66560, pipelineId=Tridion-Process-Deploy}, status=FAILED}
```

CD Storage Extension DEBUG logs shows the reason for why it is failing with 2 storage nodes

```
2019-01-05 11:07:33,982 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Configuration is: Storage(Class=com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory, Id=defaultdb, Type=persistence, dialect=MSSQL)[Pool(CheckoutTimeout=120, IdleTimeout=120, MonitorInterval=60, Size=5, Type=jdbc), DataSource(Class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource)[Property(Name=serverName, Value=SERVERNAME\SQL01), Property(Name=portNumber, Value=9561), Property(Name=databaseName, Value=Tridion_Broker_Live), Property(Name=user, Value=TridionBrokerUser), Property(Name=password, Value=Tridion)], Indexer(Class=org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer, DefaultCoreUrl=http://servername/solr/shard1_replica1, DocExtensions=txt, Mode=http)]
2019-01-05 11:07:33,982 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Using: org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer as search index class for storageId: defaultdb
2019-01-05 11:07:33,982 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Loading org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer
2019-01-05 11:07:33,997 DEBUG SolrIndexer - Configuration is: Storage(Class=com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory, Id=defaultdb, Type=persistence, dialect=MSSQL)[Pool(CheckoutTimeout=120, IdleTimeout=120, MonitorInterval=60, Size=5, Type=jdbc), DataSource(Class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource)[Property(Name=serverName, Value=SERVERNAME\SQL01), Property(Name=portNumber, Value=9561), Property(Name=databaseName, Value=Tridion_Broker_Live), Property(Name=user, Value=TridionBrokerUser), Property(Name=password, Value=Tridion)], Indexer(Class=org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer, DefaultCoreUrl=http://Servername/solr/shard1_replica1, DocExtensions=txt, Mode=http)]
2019-01-05 11:07:33,997 INFO  SolrIndexer - Setting defaultCoreUrl to: http://Servername/solr/shard1_replica1
2019-01-05 11:07:33,997 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Configured: org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer
2019-01-05 11:07:33,997 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Loaded: org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer
2019-01-05 11:07:35,341 DEBUG JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO - JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,403 DEBUG JPASearchPageDAO - JPASearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,638 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Configuration is: Storage(Class=com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory, Id=sqlserver, Type=persistence, dialect=MSSQL)[Pool(CheckoutTimeout=120, IdleTimeout=120, MonitorInterval=60, Size=5, Type=jdbc), DataSource(Class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource)[Property(Name=serverName, Value=SERVERName\SQL01), Property(Name=portNumber, Value=9561), Property(Name=databaseName, Value=Tridion_Broker_Live), Property(Name=user, Value=TridionBrokerUser), Property(Name=password, Value=Tridion)], Indexer(Class=org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer, DocExtensions=txt, access_key_id=AKIA, authentication=explicit, documentEndpoint=cloudsearch.amazonaws.com, indexBatchSize=20, secret_access_key=k7fOqM9/pS)]
2019-01-05 11:07:35,638 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Using: org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer as search index class for storageId: defaultdb
2019-01-05 11:07:35,653 DEBUG JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO - JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,653 DEBUG JPASearchPageDAO - JPASearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,669 DEBUG FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO - FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,669 DEBUG FSSearchPageDAO - FSSearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,685 DEBUG FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO - FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,685 DEBUG FSSearchPageDAO - FSSearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,685 DEBUG FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO - FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,685 DEBUG FSSearchPageDAO - FSSearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,685 DEBUG FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO - FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-05 11:07:35,685 DEBUG FSSearchPageDAO - FSSearchPageDAO init.
```

Storage extension Debug logs

```
2019-01-16 13:11:03,669 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Configuration is: Storage(Class=com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory, Id=sqlserver, Type=persistence, dialect=MSSQL)[Pool(CheckoutTimeout=120, IdleTimeout=120, MonitorInterval=60, Size=5, Type=jdbc), DataSource(Class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource)[Property(Name=serverName, Value=ServerName), Property(Name=portNumber, Value=9561), Property(Name=databaseName, Value=Tridion_Broker_Live), Property(Name=user, Value=TridionBrokerUser), Property(Name=password, Value=********)], Indexer(Class=org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer, DocExtensions=txt, access_key_id=AKIAIKEW6HC74334A75Q, authentication=explicit, documentEndpoint=cloudsearch.amazonaws.com, indexBatchSize=20, secret_access_key=********)]
2019-01-16 13:11:03,669 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Using: org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer as search index class for storageId: sqlserver
2019-01-16 13:11:03,669 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Loading org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer
2019-01-16 13:11:03,669 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Configured: org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer
2019-01-16 13:11:03,669 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Loaded: org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer
2019-01-16 13:11:05,498 DEBUG JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO - JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,560 DEBUG JPASearchPageDAO - JPASearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,763 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Configuration is: Storage(Class=com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory, Id=defaultdb, Type=persistence, dialect=MSSQL)[Pool(CheckoutTimeout=120, IdleTimeout=120, MonitorInterval=60, Size=5, Type=jdbc), DataSource(Class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource)[Property(Name=serverName, Value=ServerName), Property(Name=portNumber, Value=9561), Property(Name=databaseName, Value=Tridion_Broker_Live), Property(Name=user, Value=TridionBrokerUser), Property(Name=password, Value=********)], Indexer(Class=org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer, DefaultCoreUrl=http://ServerName/solr/, DocExtensions=txt, Mode=http)[Urls[SI4T: 
                                    The Value attribute is the complete URL to a Solr Core
                                    The Id attribute denotes a unique Tridion Publication IdUrl(Id=123, Value=http://ServerName/solr/)]]]
2019-01-16 13:11:05,763 INFO  SearchIndexProcessor - Using: org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer as search index class for storageId: sqlserver
2019-01-16 13:11:05,763 DEBUG JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO - JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,763 DEBUG JPASearchPageDAO - JPASearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,779 DEBUG FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO - FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,794 DEBUG FSSearchPageDAO - FSSearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,794 DEBUG FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO - FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,794 DEBUG FSSearchPageDAO - FSSearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,794 DEBUG FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO - FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,794 DEBUG FSSearchPageDAO - FSSearchPageDAO init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,810 DEBUG FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO - FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO Init.
2019-01-16 13:11:05,810 DEBUG FSSearchPageDAO - FSSearchPageDAO init.
```

can we configure both AWS and Solr Indexer together?
Please help me

Comment: I don't think the same storage to have multiple si4t indexers will work, why you need same publication index data details looking to index in both solr and aws cloudsearch, instead you can define separate storage id specific to publication id to index

Comment: Thanks Velmurugan, I have tried by configuring 2 storage nodes as per below update from Github                                          
  https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/issues/19                                                                                                Still I am having same issue, the first storage configured Indexer will work fine and second one will fail.

Comment: Please edit your question and share the latest error log information?

Comment: Hi Velmurugan, I updated logs and configuration

Comment: Updated logs have only DEBUG not ERROR message

Comment: Debug log showing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and Added CD Storage Extension DEBUG logs which shows the reason for why it is failing with 2 storage nodes

Comment: There is no ERROR message in above-provided logs, It's a bit difficult to say or such what would be the issue, I never did multiple indexer setups,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this updated cd_storage_config and Search DAO bundle config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="8.5" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
        <Namespace default="tcm"/>
        <Global>
            <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
                <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
                    <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
                </Policy>
                <Features>
                    <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
                </Features>
            </ObjectCache>
            <Storages>
                <StorageBindings>
                    <Bundle src="SearchDAOBundle.xml"/>
                </StorageBindings>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory" Id="sqlserver" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                    <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                        <Property Name="serverName" Value="SERVERNAME"/>
                        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_Live"/>
                        <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBroker"/>
                        <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
                    </DataSource>
                    <Indexer Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" DefaultCoreUrl="http://we100/solr/web8_shard1_replica1" DocExtensions="txt" Mode="http" />
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory" Id="defaultdb" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
                    <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
                    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                        <Property Name="serverName" Value="SERVERNAME"/>
                        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="9561"/>
                        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker_Live"/>
                        <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBroker"/>
                        <Property Name="password" Value="Tridion"/>
                    </DataSource>
                    <Indexer Class="org.si4t.cloudsearch.CloudSearchIndexer" DocExtensions="txt" access_key_id="****" authentication="explicit" documentEndpoint="****.eu-west-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com" indexBatchSize="20" secret_access_key="****"/>
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.FSSearchDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false">
                    <Root Path="D:\DevLive\live"/>
                    <Indexer Class="org.si4t.solr.SolrIndexer" DefaultCoreUrl="http://we100/solr/web8_shard1_replica1" DocExtensions="txt" Mode="http" />
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="cie_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                    <Root Path="D:\DevLive\live\C\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ocr_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                    <Root Path="D:\DevLive\live\OC\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
                </Storage>
                <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="ce_index_files" Type="filesystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">
                    <Root Path="D:\DevLive\live\EL\SearchIndex\Resources"/>
                </Storage>
            </Storages>
            <Transaction MonitorInterval="5000" Timeout="10000000"/>
        </Global>
        <ItemTypes cached="false" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
            <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
            <Publication Id="31" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
                <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="cie_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
            </Publication>
            <Publication Id="33" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
                <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="ocr_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
            </Publication>
            <Publication Id="32" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Page"/>
                <Item cached="true" storageId="defaultFile" typeMapping="Binary"/>
                <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".htm" storageId="defaultdb" typeMapping="Page"/>
                <Item cached="false" itemExtension=".xml" storageId="ce_index_files" typeMapping="ComponentPresentation"/>
            </Publication>
            <Publication Id="141" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Publication Id="142" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
            <Publication Id="123" cached="true" defaultStorageId="sqlserver"/>
        </ItemTypes>
        <ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="encrypted:****" ConnectionTimeout="20000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="http://DOMAIN-dev.:9082/discovery.svc" TokenServiceUrl="http://DOMAIN-dev.:9082/token.svc">
            <Roles>
                <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://DOMAIN-dev.:9084/httpupload">
                    <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
                </Role>
            </Roles>
        </ConfigRepository>
    </Configuration>
```

**SearchDAOBundle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StorageDAOBundle type="filesystem">
    <StorageDAO typeMapping="Page" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.FSSearchPageDAO"/>
    <StorageDAO typeMapping="Binary" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.FSSearchBinaryContentDAO"/>
    <StorageDAO typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.FSSearchComponentPresentationDAO"/>
</StorageDAOBundle>
<StorageDAOBundle type="persistence">
    <StorageDAO typeMapping="Page" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchPageDAO"/>
    <StorageDAO typeMapping="Binary" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchBinaryContentDAO"/>
    <StorageDAO typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.dao.JPASearchComponentPresentationDAO"/>
</StorageDAOBundle>
```

**Updated based on Rai findings:**

This feature should be working SI4T 1.2+ jar version (si4t-solr-1.2.jar)

To ensure SI4T 1.2 is there. That should make it work. If you need a higher version of datalayer then you should be able to get it from here: https://csei.sdl.com/hotfixes

Comment: Why we need to configure File Storage when we want only configure DB node? After above changes i am getting below error                                       
                                                                                                               
Deployment Processing Phase failed. Error creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'FSSearchDAOFactory' is defined

Comment: Search Indexing data XML which item types have? Initial error complaining about to check if the default file system is properly defined and ItemTypes defaultStorageId is correct? I was wondering default Item type for page and binary defined in the beginning it causing the issue, I'm not sure, try to keep the item tags only in the publication tag

Comment: It is still throwing same error after removing default items types, I am guessing when configured 2 storage nodes with same class com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory
In configure function of JPASearchDAOFactory will return 1st node in below line 
"final String daoFactoryClassName = configuration.getAttribute(DAO_FACTORY_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE);"

Comment: Please update your question with the latest error logs?

Comment: @PrasannaKGollamudi - that's not correct. You get one new storage factory for every configured node. What SI4T jar version are you on?

Comment: @Raimond We are using si4t-1.0.jar which is downloaded from https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/releases/download/DXA_2.0_Release/SDL.DXA.Search.Module.2.0.zip

Comment: I think that's the problem. Can you download https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/releases/download/1.2/si4t-se-1.2.jar and https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/releases/download/1.2/si4t-solr-1.2.jar and replace you current jars and try again?

Comment: After using above JAR files also same issue, when i opened the code associated with above jars I saw below code                                                                    
  public JPASearchDAOFactory (String storageId, String dialect) {
        super(storageId, dialect);
        // Needed to correctly instantiate a searchindexer
        this.storageId = storageId;
        LOG.info("Storage Id is: {}",this.storageId);
    }     it looks like only first instance is considered

Comment: Can you post / update the same initialization log please?

Comment: Posted latest Storage extension Debug logs

Comment: I tried to reproduce this locally, but with SI4T 1.2 and cd_datalayer-8.5.0-1064 it works fine. I see that two factories are instantiated and the correct DAOs are loaded for both separately. Do you maybe have a scaled out deployer?

Comment: I am configuring Solr and AWS cloud search together which is failing, hope you also tried same scenario, if possible can you post your log as answer, when I configured SI4T 1.2 it failed even with single storage configuration

Comment: Yes I did that as well obviously. See https://pastebin.com/236qFPhd.

Comment: Looks like some JAR file conflicts I might be having,I have attached jar files available in my Deployer for Solr and AWS see https://pastebin.com/fUZpRAaL and using cd_datalayer-8.5.0-1035, can you please share the list of JARS you have

Comment: Simply deduplicate all of your duplicate jar files (there are a lot) and ensure only SI4T 1.2 is there. That should make it work. If you need a higher version of datalayer then you should be able to get it from here: http://csei.sdl.com/hotfixes/

Comment: @Raimond It worked, Thank you, issue is with duplicate versions of jar files

Comment: That's great news!

Comment: @Raimond Could you please convert your findings comments to answers? so that this ticket can be resolved and complete.

Comment: @PrasannaKGollamudi - Could you please accept this answer to close this ticket